# SQL detecting increasing values

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Probably easy, but my SQL is rusty.

For simplicity's sake, I have a table NEWTABLE in which each record has six attributes, TRANSACTIONNR (primary key), SERIAL (foreign key), DATE, and OLDVOLUME. DECREASE, NEWVOLUME.

There is a daily decrease for each SERIAL, with the NEWVOLUME for today, becoming the OLDVOLUME for tomorrow.

For this table, volume is supposed to decrease over time. If OLDVOLUME is greater than the NEWVOLUME from the previous day, this is an error..

What's my SQL for finding the serial number of these erroneous records?

Comment: If you database system supports it (i.e. it's not [tag:mysql]) why not create a `CHECK` constraint that enforces this and stop the bad data getting added in the first place?

Comment: What db platform are you using?

Comment: @paqogomez using Oracle SQL Developer 11g. As I said, just trying to get to grips with SQL again, more than anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I suppose `decrease` is the delta between `oldvolume` and `newvolume` so that `newvolume = oldvolume - decrease`. You're looking for increasing, hence *negative* `decrease` values :

```
SELECT serial
FROM newtable
WHERE decrease < 0
;
```

---

EDIT : Okay, based on your updated definition, here's a [working example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4edc5/6). The idea is to perform an `INNER JOIN` from the table itself and examine the delta.

Note that this query makes the assumption that the time delta between two records is *always* one day.

```
SELECT l2.serial
FROM log AS l1
INNER JOIN log AS l2
  ON l1.date = l2.date - INTERVAL 1 DAY
WHERE
  l1.newvolume < l2.oldvolume
```

Comment: Not quite. Yes, newvolume = oldvolume - decrease. However, I'm not expecting these erroneous values to be reflected in the DECREASE. What I'm looking for, for example, is where OLDVOLUME (06 Jun) > NEWVOLUME (05 Jun). An unexplained increase, from one day to the next. @swordofpain

Comment: @user3544027, I believe thats exactly what I have in my answer.  Too simple?

Comment: No, your answer was dead on. Just realised my question was wrong. Really sorry. Have updated. SERIAL is a FK, there is a different PK.

Comment: @swordofpain Thanks for the help! Sorry to waste your time with the wrong question info.

Comment: @user3544027 No problem ;-) The question was'nt *wrong*, just a bit unclear